# disable mootools sortable function without editing original

Tags: javascript, mootools

i've never worked with mootools before , i have to kill this specific sortable function , but i can not edit the original script , so i need to recall the function and disable it from triggering

any help ?

```js
new Sortables('.homepagemodule CAPTION', {
  clone: true,
  revert: true,
  opacity: 0.7,
  onStart: function() {
    dndMovingModule = this.element.parentNode.parentNode.id.toUpperCase();
  },
  onComplete: function() {
    dndDroppedOntoModule = this.element.parentNode.parentNode.id.toUpperCase();
    if (
      typeof dndMovingModule != "undefined"
      && typeof dndDroppedOntoModule != "undefined"
      && dndMovingModule != dndDroppedOntoModule
    ) {
      var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/"
        + year + "/save_setting?L=" + league_id + "&TITLE=MODULE&VALUE="
        + dndMovingModule + "," + dndDroppedOntoModule;
      // alert("calling: " + url);
      makeHttpRequest(url);
      setTimeout("window.location.reload();", 250);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`removeEvents()` removes all mootools event listeners from a node.

Given your code, `$$('.homepagemodule CAPTION').removeEvents()` should do the trick.